# Merge multiple animated GIFs to a single one in Android

Tags: android, merge, gif

My goal is to allow the users of my app to select different gif-files and put them together. Afterwards they should be able to watch their individual combination of the files. At first sight it seemed easy to me to implement such a function but i was wrong. I tried different things, such as

- building a byte-array with the selected gif-files after each other and save it as a new gif-file
- using the class AnimationDrawable to display the gifs after each other
- using the Movie-class to play the files after each other

I am not sure which one of these ways would be the best. However, in the end none of these approaches worked properly anyway... If anyone of you ever had the same problem, i would be very happy for some help.

Comment: Did you the solution of this issue. I have same problem

Comment: @Akanksha no, i didn't. However, I found another way which worked for me. Instead of using GIFs, I decided to use AnimationDrawables. The class AnimationDrawable has a method called addFrame() which allows you to easily put Animations thogether.

Comment: @Akanksha any solution? Same problem

Answer (score -1):

You can not merge GIF images , But if you want to put them together you can take **GridView**. Make **customGifView** by extending the **View** class.

Comment: If you think that programmer cannot merge GIF images so how you will explain this functionality https://ezgif.com/help/merging-gifs?